# chooseBestHostPlayerWithCompletionHandler returns null

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

The following code returns best host as null.  How can I get it to work?

```
[gameKitHelper.match chooseBestHostPlayerWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSString *playerID) {
    gameKitHelper.hostingPlayer = [playerID retain];
    NSLog(@"Best host = %@",gameKitHelper.hostingPlayer);
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's Game Center Guide

> If you intend to search for the best server using this method, all
>   devices in the match must be running on versions of Game Kit that
>   support this method, and every device in the match must call this
>   method at the same time.

Do you do that in your app?

Also in order for this to work all the clients must be already connected to each other.

Comment: I'm running on 1 ipad simulator and 1 ipad both with IOS 6.1.  They connect with each other fine, but return best host returns NULL

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work with the simulator (or I haven't been able to make it work).

I do get a valid result most of the time when using 2 devices. That said - it's not always consistent (maybe it's just the sandbox API), so you definitely need a backup option for choosing the host.

Comment: I can confirm what @Andrew said. It's not working for me in the Simulator either and sometimes it returns null between devices. So a backup option is needed. Maybe Apple will update the docs with this information. Also one other issue I'm facing is that it takes quite a bit of time for the method to return, even if the result is null. So I'm debating if I'm gonna use it at all.

Comment: @Andrew do you generate a random number to determine a host then (that's what I'm doing)? is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah I'm also using a RNG to figure out the host. And I'll probably drop the chooseBestHost, because it takes a lot of time and it fails far too often to be worth it.

Comment: I too am having the same issue, between device/simulator or two devices (both running the latest iOS 7.0.4). It takes 6-7 seconds for the method to return nil, every time. I'm curious if it works better in the development Game Center, but I don't want to risk leaving it in my code and cause a bad user experience. I like the solution @Gujamin uses, but I wish this method actually worked as advertised.

Answer (score 5):

I found a simple solution (instead of generating a random number which requires additional negotiation and data transfer) is to simply compare [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] playerID] with the playerIDs in the match and choose the first one ordered ascending.  This can be done on all the devices, guarantees a unique playerID as host and guarantees the same unique playerID is chosen on all devices.